# Easily bulk import Outlook 2007 calendar items

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar, ics

Ever since I've been at the place I work, the method that has been used to share calendar items has been for the person that manages the calendar to send out appointment invites to everyone. This is really annoying for everyone because at the beginning of the school year (it's a school that I work at) there are literally a couple hundred invites sent out at once (all of the events for the coming year) and they have to be manually accepted. I've been scratching my head trying to figure out an EASY way to get all of those appointments into peoples' individual calendars. I can create a .ics file that contains everything but there is no EASY way to import it. I realize it can be done by going to File > Import and Export... but I know that at least half of my users would be unwilling or unable to do it and I would end up doing it for them - I'm trying to avoid that while still making it convenient for them.

So my question is: Is there a way to EASILY bulk import calendar items? A script or something?

Comment: Why not just teach people how to open a shared calendar?

Comment: I knew someone would ask that. Although I could elaborate in great detail, suffice to say that doing it that way is not convenient for us. I think having to explain any further than that defeats the spirit of StackExchange. It might as well be a message board otherwise (which is where I would expect a comment like yours).

Comment: No Vincent, the idea of Stack Exchange is to get you the best answer, which is not always what you ask for, or even expect. If you're asking help from subject experts, you should be prepared to listen to our advice when we think you may be going about something the wrong way. If you explain your reasons for not wanting a shared calendar, we can better understand your problem and maybe give you a more informed answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several pay-for utilities available to do this

http://www.calendar-import-export.com/

You probably could create your own using the office API's as well. Might want to ask that question at stackoverflow.